# AEM 6.2 application pages are giving very high load times and author environment goes unresponsive

Tags: performance, performance-testing, aem

How do i bundle up my clientlibs so that the ones meant to load up only in author do not load up in publish?
Also how can i improve the load time of my AEM site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various factors that needs to take care when you are considering of performance

1) **clientlibs**

AEM can deliver enhanced performance by enabling Minify (Minify compresses JS and CSS using the YUI compressor) and Gzip (Gzip is an algorithm that can compress a file ten-fold) in the Day CQ HTML Library Manager of the Felix Configuration console.
[image]

2) If any Search functionality implementation (Creating the OAK indexing for search functionality and suggestions)

3) If more content and SQL usage (Think about the MongoDB and clusters)

4) If any external relational data base connections needed for the content
Optimize the connection establishment and livetimes of connections/sessions, Queries to retrieve data like SQL queries

5) The optimization of JS functions if any framework usage like angular-JS integrations.

6) Usage of sightly (now called as HTML Template Language by Adobe)
7) Hardware requirement (https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/manage/hardware-sizing-guidelines.html)

8) Dispatcher Caching is the one which will play a key role for the performance/security

9) etc,.

Some Good articles that you can find

> https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/configuring/performance.html
>   https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/performance-tuning-tips.html
>   https://hashimkhan.in/2015/10/07/guidelines-for-performance-optimziation/